# Go Cardless API - Company list - how to limit the list to active customers only?

Tags: php, gocardless

within laravel PHP, I recently realised that the list of companies returned is the full list of companies, including the ones that Go Cardless deem as inactive...

I would like to limit the list to active customers only.

I'm using a simple lookup as follows:

```
$client = new Client([
      'access_token' => env('GOCARDLESS_TOKEN','none'),
      'environment' => env('GOCARDLESS_ENV','none')
    ]);

$customers = $client->customers()->list()->records;
```

I'm guessing I need some params to limit the list, but its not obvious what, from the API documentation...

Or even if its possible from this one lookup...

Anyone else know what is required?

Comment: Is "company" and "customer" supposed to be the same thing? https://developer.gocardless.com/api-reference/#customers-list-customers doesn't appear to list any filtering parameter relating to any active/inactive status.

Comment: That is my impression to. Just wondered if anyone else knew something I didn't.